# Proof that $ab/(a+c)$ is bounded for bounded $b$ and $c$

Tags: proof-writing

Is there a concise way to prove that $\frac{ab}{a+c} \in [0, 1]$ for all $a > 0$, $b \in [0, 1]$, and $c \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: Note that $0\leq ab\leq a\leq a+c$. Then you can get the conclusion.

Comment: @molan Perfect, thanks! Make it an answer and it gets my vote.

Comment: No thanks. But I think it don't deserve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\leq \frac{ab}{a+c}=\frac{b}{1+\frac{c}{a}}\leq b\leq 1$$

Comment: You could add $0 \le$ on the left hand side and $\le 1$ on the right

Comment: You also should assume that $a\not=0$.

Comment: It is given that $a>0$